# Relation between number of blocks of threads

Tags: cuda

This code is from a book called cuda by examples

```
#include "../common/book.h"
#define N (33 * 1024)

__global__ void add( int *a, int *b, int *c ) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while (tid < N) {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }  
}

                   .
                   .
                   .
add<<<128,128>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c );
```

33*1024 = 33792

128 * 128 = 16384

33792 > 16384

So, can I have to increase the number of threads per blocks in this case to run?

Answer (score 5):

Notice the second command in the body of while-cycle, i.e. `tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;`. It does the stuff even for bigger arrays than 16384.

Thread with ID 0 sums the items of arrays in the positions 0, 16384, 32768,... 
Thread with ID 1 sums the items of arrays in the positions 1, 16385, 32769,...

Comment: Sorry @stuhlo, but I capture the values of tid (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) 
and offset ( tid+ (blockDim.x * gridDim.x) ) and I get this: 


thread id       0 address:    16384   
thread id       1 address:    16385   
thread id       2 address:    16386   
...
thread id   16384 address:    32768   <-- would be thread id 0?
thread id   16385 address:    32769   <-- i have only 128 blocks in X and 128 threads per blocks = 128 * 128 = (16384 < 16385)
thread id   16386 address:    32770

Comment: @user916933 `tid` is just variable and each thread has its own variables. At the beginning it keeps unique ID of each launched thread, i.e. it has values from 0 to 16383. Afterwards, it is used for keeping indices which each thread accesses but "real" ID of thread is not modified.

Comment: if I use the following code:

add<<<128,128>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c );

what is the maximum value of N that I can use?

Comment: @user916933 It is unlimited. In a case `add<<<128,128>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c );` you launch 16384 threads and depending on N each thread sums zero, one or more numbers.